# Sorting Nested Lists in two different orders

Tags: python, list

I have the below list.

```
[[1, [400, 'London']],
 [1, [420, 'Paris']],
 [2, [430, 'London']],
 [2, [440, 'Paris']],
 [3, [550, 'Mumbai']],
 [3, [460, 'Paris']],
 [4, [560, 'Mumbai']],
 [4, [510, 'Dubai']],
 [5, [525, 'Dubai']],
 [5, [520, 'London']],
 [6, [550, 'London']],
 [6, [520, 'Paris']],
 [7, [580, 'London']],
 [7, [540, 'Paris']]]
```

I wanted to sort the list in descending order based on the first value inside the nested lists. For example,

```
[[1, [420, 'Paris']]],
 [1, [400, 'London']],
 [2, [440, 'Paris']],
 [2, [430, 'London']]]
```

and so on..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `l` the input, use `sorted` with the `key` parameter:

```py
l2 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1][0]))
```

Inverting the second number sorts it by decreasing value.

output:

```
[[1, [420, 'Paris']],
 [1, [400, 'London']],
 [2, [440, 'Paris']],
 [2, [430, 'London']],
 [3, [550, 'Mumbai']],
 [3, [460, 'Paris']],
 [4, [560, 'Mumbai']],
 [4, [510, 'Dubai']],
 [5, [525, 'Dubai']],
 [5, [520, 'London']],
 [6, [550, 'London']],
 [6, [520, 'Paris']],
 [7, [580, 'London']],
 [7, [540, 'Paris']]]
```